# SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, segmentation-fault

Usually app works great, but i received issue in Crashlytics. It's happen 1-2 times in day. For 2k-3k users. App work on iOS 7 and later. Here stack of thread where app crashed

```
     Thread : Crashed: ACAccountStoreReply
     0  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018546f418 WTFCrash + 72
     1  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018546f410 WTFCrash + 64
     2  WebCore                        0x000000018d7f22a4 _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 256
     3  WebCore                        0x000000018d7f3298 WebThreadLock + 104
     4  UIKit                          0x00000001871e2e30 -[UIWebView _webViewCommonInitWithWebView:scalesPageToFit:shouldEnableReachability:] + 140
     5  UIKit                          0x000000018732a418 -[UIWebView initWithCoder:] + 132
     6  UIKit                          0x000000018740b90c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 816
     7  UIKit                          0x000000018740b5cc -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 120
     8  UIKit                          0x0000000187357714 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 128
     9  UIKit                          0x000000018740b90c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 816
     10 UIKit                          0x000000018740b874 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 664
     11 UIKit                          0x000000018740b5cc -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 120
     12 UIKit                          0x0000000187356cb8 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 952
     13 UIKit                          0x000000018729b878 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
     14 UIKit                          0x0000000186f9c488 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 88
     15 UIKit                          0x0000000186f9c3f4 -[UIViewController view] + 32
     16 UIKit                          0x000000018701b194 -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 68
     17 UIKit                          0x000000018701b0cc -[UIViewController _visibleView] + 84
     18 UIKit                          0x0000000187093614 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 4396
     19 UIKit                          0x0000000187091a9c -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 5184
     20 MYAPP                       0x0000000100021fb8 -[RegularTweetsViewController didSelectContexMenuInCell:withURL:] (RegularTweetsViewController.m:516)
     21 MYAPP                       0x0000000100021ab4 __55-[RegularTweetsViewController tweetCellRetweetPressed:]_block_invoke233 (RegularTweetsViewController.m:476)
     22 MYAPP                       0x0000000100023af8 __74-[RegularTweetsViewController retweetWithData:andAccount:success:failure:]_block_invoke (RegularTweetsViewController.m:841)
     23 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190ab4014 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
     24 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190ab3fd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
     25 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190ab9654 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 152
     26 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190ab3fd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
     27 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190abb2b8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 556
     28 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190abb4fc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 76
     29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000190c496bc _pthread_wqthread + 356
```

App crashed here. In this function:

```
     20 MYAPP                       0x0000000100021fb8 -[RegularTweetsViewController didSelectContexMenuInCell:withURL:] (RegularTweetsViewController.m:516)
```

Function code:

```
- (void) didSelectContexMenuInCell:(TweetCell *)tweetCell withURL:(NSURL *)url
{
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:tweetCell];

  if (indexPath != nil)
    {//516 line **HERE CRASH**
        TweetVMData *data = [self.viewModel dataForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        WebViewController *webController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [self presentViewController:webController animated:YES completion:nil];

        data.openMenu = NO;

        TweetsViewModel *viewModel = (TweetsViewModel *)self.viewModel;
        viewModel.indexPathOfOpenMenu = nil;
        viewModel.hasOpenMenu = NO;
    }
}
```

I haven't idea why this happens.

Comment: Not sure from what you posted but it looks as if you're doing UI-related things on a thread other than the main one.

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks Phillip! I thought so too, but was not sure. Yesterday i send update to App Store. Soon it becomes clear what the problem was